# LINQ to Dictionary - Using XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have already asked a simular question, granted, however, this one is different and I have tried.

I was attempting to read XML data using Linq and I sorted this problem out, however, I need to select multiple values and store these into a Dictionary. I have tried (and the comments are my attempts) but I just cannot figure it out and get an error like:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at dsdsdsds.MainClass+c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0 (System.Xml.Linq.XElement datanum) [0x00000] in /Users/p/Projects/dsdsdsds/dsdsdsds/Main.cs:23

Let's assume my XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
     <Document>
       <name>My word place</name>
         <Placemark>
           <name>Main Building</name> 
             <id>1</id>
               <Polygon>
            <extrude>1</extrude>
         <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
       <outerBoundaryIs>
    <LinearRing>
 <coordinates>
```

Now what I need to get is the "name" and the "id" and put these values into a dictionary.

Here is my code:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load ("buildings.kml");
        XNamespace kml = "http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2";

        var dict = xdoc.Descendants(kml + "Placemark").ToDictionary (

            datanum => datanum.Attribute(kml + "name").Value,
            datanum => datanum.Attribute(kml + "id").Value );

            /*.ToDictionary(e => e.Element("name").Value,
                                 e => e.Descendants("id")
                                    .Select (item => new Building
                                    {
                                        BuildingName = (string) e.Element(kml + "name").Value,
                                        BuildingID = Convert.ToInt16(item.Element(kml + "id").Value)
                                    }).ToList()
                                    );
        /*

        /*var buildings = xdoc.Descendants (kml + "Placemark")
            .Select((element, index) => new Building {
                BuildingName = (string) element.Element(kml + "name"),
                BuildingID = (int) element.Element(kml + "id")
            });
        */
```

Note: I have made three attempts to do this, however, getting the same / similar error messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`name` and `id` are *elements*, not *attributes*. Consequently, you need to use `Element()` instead of `Attribute()`:

```
var dict = xdoc.Descendants(kml + "Placemark")
               .ToDictionary(datanum => datanum.Element(kml + "name").Value,
                             datanum => datanum.Element(kml + "id").Value);
```

If `name` or `id` are optional tags you can use the following code to avoid a `NullReferenceException`:

```
var dict = doc.Descendants(kml + "Placemark")
              .Select(x => new { name = (string)x.Element(kml + "name"),
                                 id = (string)x.Element(kml + "id") })
              .Where(x => x.name != null)
              .ToDictionary(x => x.name, x => x.id);
```

Please note: This simply ignores `Placemark` tags without a `name` tag. `Placemark` tags with only a `name` tag and without an `id` tag are still taken into account.

BTW: Your formatting masks this quite well, but the XML you provided in your question is not valid. Correctly formatted, this becomes obvious:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Document>
  <name>My word place</name>
  <Placemark>
    <name>Main Building</name> 
    <id>1</id>
    <Polygon>
      <extrude>1</extrude>
      <altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
      <outerBoundaryIs>
        <LinearRing>
          <coordinates>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried the code that you posted, however, I got the same error: "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at dsdsdsds.MainClass+<Main>c__AnonStorey0.<>m__1 (System.Xml.Linq.XElement datanum) [0x00000] in /Users/ph/Projects/dsdsdsds/dsdsdsds/Main.cs:19"

Comment: @Phorce: That means that there are `Placemark` without an `id` or a `name` tag. Is that allowed?

Comment: No. There are "id" and "name" tags within the XML (I think this is what you mean) every instance where "Placemark" exists

Comment: @Phorce: If that were the case, this exception wouldn't happen. At least not in the code I gave you. Please upload the complete file so I can show you the offending tag. Anyway, I updated my answer with a version that supports XML with possible missing tags.